# PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist V$SQL

Tags: database, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have created a procedure and used the below statement inside that .

```
select sql_id into v_sql_id from v_$sql where sql_text =v_sql;
```

I am getting the following error `PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

I have checked the synonym its owner is `PUBLIC`,so it should run in this case ,but its not working .

Another thing i can `select sql_id  from v_$sql where sql_text =v_sql;` this in simple editor .Can anyone help me with this .

Comment: On my system, the view is called `v$sql`, not `v_$sql`.

Comment: @Codo:On mine its V$sql only ,its under `sys` schema

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Database dictionary related or system tables (v_$sql in this case) are owned by Oracle `sys` user and needs special privileges to access them. You need to login to oracle database as `sysdba user` or get those privilages (your DBA might help you with this) to get access for the data dictionary views.

As mentioned in [this article](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/err/ora_00942.html)

```
The problem is that procedures don't respect roles; only directly granted rights 
are respected. So, that means that table_owner has to regrant the right to select
```

So, try the following to grant the SELECT on all dictionay view so that you can use it in your pl/sql blocks.

```
grant select any dictionary to USERNAME
```

Comment: Regarding logging in as sysdba, you could do that via sqlplus with: sqlplus "/ as sysdba"

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the user you are using was given access to the view through a role rather than the select privilege directly.

Unfortunately privileges obtained through a role are not active when running PL/SQL.

You need to ask your DBA to grant the SELECT privilege directly to your user.

Comment: Ok i will ask my DBA for the same .

Answer (score -2):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098870/my-oracle-view-uses-a-table-that-doesnt-exist-but-i-can-still-query-it/20473024#20473024).  It might be because you are using specific capitalisation somewhere